# Он сценарист в этом фильме(,) и он режиссёр

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, члены-предложения, и

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении?

*Он сценарист в этом фильме(,) и он режиссёр.*

Можно ли считать фразу «в этом фильме» общим членом предложения?

Фраза «в этом фильме» обстоятельство места?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас совершенно ненужное повторение местоимения. Лучше сказать так:

> В этом фильме он и сценарист, и режиссёр.